# What is the property of sound that Allows it not to travel in vacuum?

Tags: acoustics, vacuum

What is the property of sound that makes it does not travel in a vacuum.

Comment: Well, sound is "made of" moving particles. In vacuum there are no particles, so there couldn't be sound

Comment: One could also wonder how sound can travel in a medium that is 99.9 % vacuum (air in standard conditions).

Comment: @Pieter: The mean-free path is short and  collision relaxation time  is much much less than the period of the sound wave. When these conditions are violated (very high frequency or low density) sound ceases to propagate.

Comment: Pressure. You cannot have pressure variation without pressure.

Answer (score 4):

Sound is a compression/stress/particle-displacement wave in a medium. If there is no medium there is nothing to compress, so there is no sound.

Comment: Note: the medium can also be a solid.

Comment: I took the liberty of deleting the word "fluid".